# How to programmatically push content to Facebook Page wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Fact: if I manually add a link to my page's wall, that link will show up in the news feed of any Liker's of my page.  Example: user Joe likes http://facebook.com/soccer-page.  Sam, who is the admin of soccer-page, posts a link to the wall of soccer-page, Joe sees that link show up in his news feed.

Question: using .NET or jQuery, how can I programmatically add a link to a page's wall, such that once it's added, the link will show up in all the Likers' news feeds?  In the case of the example above, let's say I have a task that runs once a day that grabs the latest soccer-related article from an RSS feed. I want that task to post it for me to the soccer page's wall.

Any info would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be found here - [facebook c# sdk - The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216289/facebook-c-sdk-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-this-acti)

Answer (score 4):

Look at [this](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/28001) article

I found `FacebookService.API.stream.publish(...);`

**EDIT**: And i found better one [Post stories to your facebook wall from asp.net web app](http://forums.asp.net/t/1438976.aspx)

Comment: this is great info, thanks! question: do you know how I can get the api key & secret that belongs to the page?  remember: I am wanting to publish to a facebook page, not a facebook app.  Thanks!

Comment: Dear Ian, only i found this web app, maybe there is a facebook page process like this, actually i don't know..