# facebook c# sdk - The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: c#, facebook

I am building a console app that will publish streams to a page's wall.

Issue: I'm getting "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".  I'm using opengraph to get the access token.

Am I missing something?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
// constants
string apiKey = "XXX";
string secret = "XXX";
string pageId = "XXX";

// get access token
string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials", apiKey, secret); // todo: figure out open graph url
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
string respStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
string accessToken = respStr.Replace("access_token=", "");

// construct the post
dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
messagePost.access_token = accessToken;
messagePost.picture = "www.google.com/pic.png";
messagePost.link = "www.google.com";
messagePost.name = "some name";
messagePost.captiion = "some caption";
messagePost.description = "some description";
messagePost.req_perms = "publish_stream";
messagePost.scope = "publish_stream";

// using client
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

try // to post the post to the page's wall
{
    var result = client.Post(string.Format("/{0}/feed", pageId), messagePost); 
}
    catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
{
    // getting caught here, with error msg = "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"
}
catch (FacebookApiException ex)
{
    // ignore
}
```

Comment: Ain't this error because any facebook application must be accepted by the user, the first time, for this application to be allowed to post something on his/her page? I understand you don't want the user to have to click, but the user HAS to accept something the first time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743896/fbconnect-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-this-action.

Comment: @Tipx, thanks for your comment. Do you know how a user can accept the facebook app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After visiting the following links, I was able to run the code and have it successfully publish to the page's wall, after which it shows up in the Likers' news feeds.

http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key={API_KEY_GOES_HERE}&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&req_perms=read_stream,publish_stream

http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?api_key={API_KEY_GOES_HERE}&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?xxRESULTTOKENxx&display=popup&ext_perm=publish_stream&profile_selector_ids={PAGE_ID_GOES_HERE}

Thanks to the answer on [Authorizing a Facebook Fan Page for Status Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097665/authorizing-a-facebook-fan-page-for-status-updates)

Comment: FWIW, these days I think the profile_selector is gone, which makes this solution no longer quite correct.  (At least, if there is a replacement for profile_selector, I haven't seen it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045317/status-of-enable-profile-selector-with-oauth-2 ) these days allegedly manage_pages is all you need, then you grab the page's access token to post to it.

Answer (score 0):

"Liking your application" and "allowing your application to post to his wall" are two different sentences. There is no magic wand that allows you to override a user's preference whether they like you or not.

Your best bet is to handle the "failure" and move on to the next person. If you want to know likers that don't want you to post to their wall, you can get that information in the return and store it in some type of "log".

Comment: Hi Gregory, thanks for your comment!  I just updated the description.  I'm just looking at how to publish a post to a page's wall using facebook c# sdk.