# Status of enable_profile_selector with oauth 2

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0, facebook-social-plugins

With the new OAuth2 JavaScript SDK calls, I see no documentation for enable_profile_selector.  How do we get permissions to post to a fan page from the JavaScript SDK?

Or, is the idea that once they've given us manage_pages permission on their account, we can request access tokens and do everything without additional permission on any page?

It does appear that after being granted manage_page permissions, running this fql query returns no results:

> select publish_stream from permissions where uid = FAN_PAGE_ID

This used to be how we'd verify that we have permission to post to the page.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: ...and then, out of the blue, that query started saying we have permission.  Would love for this behavior to be documented and codified.  I feel like it could be cut off at any moment.